# Is Microcurrent Therapy effective to treat tendinitis?

Tags: healthcare

I have read a few claims that Microcurrent Therapy is effective to treat tendinitis, as illustrated below.

[What is Microcurrent Therapy?](https://web.archive.org/web/20161209090547/http://www.drwhitaker.com/what-is-microcurrent-therapy/):

> Each tissue type in your body has its own signature electrical
> frequency, which may be disrupted by injury or disease. Microcurrent
> therapy simply restores normal frequencies within the cells, resulting
> in remarkable improvements in pain, inflammation and function.
>
> What Conditions Is Microcurrent Therapy Good For?
>
> [...]
>
> Tendon and ligament pain

[PainMaster Microcurrent-Therapy Patch](http://www.groupon.com/deals/gg-painmaster-microcurrent-therapy-patch-3):

> Helps increase blood flow and reduce inflammation

The [Wikipedia page on Microcurrent electrical neuromuscular stimulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcurrent_electrical_neuromuscular_stimulator#Effectivity) contains a succinct section on effectivity but it lacks references:

> A study by a neuroretinologist in the late 1980s suggested that
> microcurrent stimulation of acupuncture points for the eye had
> positive effects in slowing and even stopping progression of macular
> degeneration[citation needed]. This treatment is used to treat both
> the Wet and Dry forms of AMD. This study was based on Ngok Cheng's
> research on the increased amounts of ATP levels in living tissue after
> being stimulated with microcurrent.[7] Several similar studies are
> currently under way and other studies have shown there are benefits
> (with specific microcurrent polarities and frequencies) on the healing
> of tendon and bone.

Is Microcurrent Therapy effective to treat tendinitis?

Comment: Anything that says "Each tissue type in your body has its own signature electrical frequency" is surely flim-flam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the systematic review {1}, there isn't enough evidence as to judge whether Microcurrent Therapy is effective to treat a tendinopathy:

> Microcurrent therapy may also be a worthwhile intervention for this condition, based on a single RCT.

The systematic study dates back from 2012, so the medical knowledge we have changed since then.

---

References:

- {1} Sussmilch-Leitch, S.P., Collins, N.J., Bialocerkowski, A.E. et al. Physical therapies for Achilles tendinopathy: systematic review and meta-analysis. J Foot Ankle Res 5, 15 (2012). https://doi.org/10.1186/1757-1146-5-15

Comment: Or at least, as of 2012 there wasn't enough evidence.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks. Good point. I'll add that in the answer